# tensorflow DNN with two hidden layers significantly slower and produce much worse result than using scikit flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, skflow

my bio dataset has 20K rows and 170 feature. I'm doing dnn regression to predict bioactivity. ( one unit output layer with linear equation and two hidden layers).  It ran very slow on my cpu and produced really bad r-square (negative).  Then I ran it with skflow with the same network architecture. It was way way faster (more than 100x) and I got r2 much better than the previous run (r2=0.3), although not a great result. Does anyone know why? anything wrong with my code? what is the difference between my code and  underlying skflow code?  is my loss function defined correctly?
Help is very much appreciated. 
Below are the codes:

```
# with scikit flow 
dnn_reg = skflow.TensorFlowDNNRegressor(hidden_units=[200,500], steps=3000, learning_rate=0.5)
dnn_reg.fit(x_train, y_train)
pred_train = dnn_reg.predict (x_train)
pred_valid = dnn_reg.predict (x_valid)
print ('r-square for training set', r2_score(y_train, pred_train))
print ('r-square for validation set',r2_score(y_valid, pred_valid))

# tensorflow code

n_samples = 15000
n_features = 171
batch_size = 1000
num_batch = n_samples/batch_size
hidden1 = 200
hidden2 = 100
learning_rate=0.01
n_epoch=3000

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    #constant and palceholder    
    tf_train_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, n_features))
    tf_train_act = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size))
    tf_valid_data=tf.constant (x_valid.astype(np.float32))


    # variables
    w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_features, hidden1]), name='weight1')
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden1]), name='bias1')
    w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden1, hidden2]), name='weight2')
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden2]), name='bias2')
    w3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden2, 1]), name='weight3')
    b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name='bias3')

    #parameter histogram    
    w1_hist = tf.histogram_summary('weight_input', w1)
    w2_hist = tf.histogram_summary('weight2', w2)
    w3_hist = tf.histogram_summary('weight3', w3)
    b1_hist = tf.histogram_summary('bias1', b1)
    b2_hist = tf.histogram_summary('bias2', b2)
    b3_hist = tf.histogram_summary('bias3', b3)
    #y_hist = tf.histogram_summary('y', y_train)   

    #training computation
    def forward_prop (input):
        with tf.name_scope('hidden_1') as scope:
            h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, w1)+b1)
        with tf.name_scope('hidden_2') as scope:
            h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h1, w2)+b2)
        with tf.name_scope('output') as scope: 
            output = tf.matmul(h2, w3)+b3
        return (output)

    #forward propagation
    output = forward_prop(tf_train_data)
    with tf.name_scope('cost') as scope:

        loss=tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(tf_train_act, output))))
        cost_summary = tf.scalar_summary('cost', loss)

    #optimizer
    with tf.name_scope('train') as scope: 
        optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

    #predictions
        train_prediction = output
        valid_prediction = forward_prop(tf_valid_data)



with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:

    session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print ('initialized')

    merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter ('./logs/log1', session.graph)

    for epoch in range(n_epoch):
        mini = np.array_split(range(y_train.shape[0]), num_batch)
        for idx in mini[:-1]:
            batch_x = x_train[idx]
            batch_y = y_train[idx]
            feed_dict = {tf_train_data:batch_x, tf_train_act:batch_y}
            _,l, pred_train = session.run([optimizer, loss, output], feed_dict=feed_dict)

        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print ('minibatch loss at step %d: %f' % (epoch, l))
            print ('minibatch r2: %0.1f' % r2_score(batch_y, pred_train))
            print ('validation r2: %0.1f' % r2_score(y_valid, valid_prediction.eval()))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of parameters that are different between your `TensorFlowDNNRegressor` and vanilla tensorflow model including:

`hidden2 = 100`

`learning_rate=0.01`

`batch_size=1000`, the default `batch_size` for `TensorFlowDNNRegressor` is 32. I think that's the main reason why `TensorFlowDNNRegressor` runs much faster.

Also, `TensorFlowDNNRegressor` use SGD as default optimizer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I did change the parameter and got almost the same hugh speed difference. flor skflow, it only took less than one min. while my program needs more than 15 mins.   There must be something else big.  Is my loss function right?  Do you see anything wrong with my code?    I just checked.  The default optimizer  of TensorFlowDNNRegressor appears to be 'Adagrad'.

Comment: @j.zheng, can you try changing to `loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(output - tf.expand_dims(tf_train_act, dim=[1])))` ? That's the same loss function used in the [source code of skflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c43a32d5d0929170a057862e2cd0b59308421444/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py#L773).

Comment: @j.zheng, alternatively, you can set `tf_train_act = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, 1))`

Comment: no luck. still huge difference. skflow finished in around half min. my code took long long time.  something gotta be wrong.   maybe the way I did minibatch is different from skflow? or something else?

Comment: did you ever  compare performance of any of your tensorflow code and skflow?   In this case, not just speed but also r2 is a lot worse.  something must be wrong with my code...  spend hours but could not figure out. thanks  for you help.

Comment: @j.zheng, unfortunately I haven't. I think the last idea I can think of is to remove all the summary/logging parts in the tensorflow.